# Gradle sync failed: Expected configuration ':backend:appengineSdk' to contain exactly one file, however, it contains no files

Tags: android, google-app-engine, gradle, firebase

I followed the tutorial [here](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/firebase-app-engine-android-studio) to setup my Android app with Firebase and Google App Engine. Everything worked fine until I added the Google App Engine module, and then the following error occurred during gradle build:

```
Gradle sync failed: Expected configuration ':backend:appengineSdk' to contain exactly one file, however, it contains no files.
```

Anyone have any ideas? There are no reference for this type of error and I am lost!

My project gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My app gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.joelmin.sharemon"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
}
```

App engine gradle:

```
// If you would like more information on the gradle-appengine-plugin please refer to the github page
// https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.28'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

dependencies {
}

appengine {
  downloadSdk = true
  appcfg {
    oauth2 = true
  }
}
```

Comment: I think appengineSdk is not downloaded correctly.

Comment: How would I download it again? I've added it as a gradle dependency and Android Studio just downloads it itself...

Comment: btw I can see it correctly downloaded in ~/.gradle/caches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I fixed this by deleting the existing app engine module, and re-creating a new module with a **different name** and then all worked fine...weird...

Comment: In my case this was caused because gradle mismatch. My feature module depended on library modules. I made a mistake, and specified 'apply plugin: 'com.android.feature' instead of 'apply plugin: 'com.android.library'. in module's build.gradle.